# admin rights required to update system c runtime for python

Tags: python

I'm bundling a Python installer (python 3.7.3) from Python.org. I plan on using the silent mode install as part of a larger installer.

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution), within the installation notes it states if the user selects "install now":

> You will not need to be an administrator (unless a system update for the C Runtime Library is required or you install the Python Launcher for Windows for all users)

However I have already installed python 3.7.3 on my system and when browsing the installation directory I can see a copy of `vcruntime140.dll` is present in the installation directory root. I've opted in this to install it to my c: root so I don't need admin rights.

I presume that administrator rights are required to install the aforementioned DLL in `c:\windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll` and such but if it's bundled within the installation directory, why would updating the system runtime be required at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a documentation error. [Here](https://bugs.python.org/file37752/README.txt) is how the installer really works (or at least supposed to):

```
When installed for all users, the following files are installed to
either "%SystemRoot%\System32" or "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64" as
appropriate. For the current user, they are installed in the Python
install directory.

.\python3x.dll      The core interpreter
.\python3.dll       The stable ABI reference
.\appcrt140.dll     Microsoft Visual C Runtime
.\desktopcrt140.dll Microsoft Visual C Runtime
.\vcruntime140.dll  Microsoft Visual C Runtime

When installed for all users, the following files are installed to
"%SystemRoot%" (typically "C:\Windows") to ensure they are always
available on PATH. (See Launching Python below.) For the current user,
they are installed in the Python install directory.

.\py[w].exe         PEP 397 launcher
```