# Does python depend on microsoft visual c++ redistributable?

Tags: python, electron, pyinstaller

1. Does python require microsoft visual c++ redistributable to run the code ?

I'm using pyinstaller to compile my .py code into exe. In some systems my exe is asking for microsoft visual c++ redistributable package to run.

2. Does pyinstaller includes microsoft visual c++ redistributable files while making exe ? If no, how can I include those files so that I don't need to install microsoft visual c++ redistributable package into other's system to run my software ?
3. What are the other alternatives to build a standalone software in python ? I'm reading to use other languages along with python.
4. I saw electron js and python can be used together to make desktop application. But how will I distribute that application as a standalone exe ?

Answer (score 3):

Python itself does not depend on the presence of MSVC. You can download a portable Python package, and it will run wherever you copy it. Those are the `embeddable` ones from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

But, Python modules with native extension code inside can depend on MSVC on multiple levels:

- if the native part comes in binary format (`.pyd` file on Windows), actually that is a `.dll`, and it may depend on other `.dll`-s, depending on how it has been built
- if the native part comes as C/C++ source code, it will be built at installation time, typically via a "[`setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-with-distutils)", and this procedure will need a C compiler installed on the system

PyInstaller is a different story. First of all, it has a documentation which you may want to read. For example the page [What PyInstaller Does and How It Does It](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html) clearly gives a direct answer to at least one of your questions:

> **Bundling to One File**
>
> PyInstaller can bundle your script and all its dependencies into a single executable named myscript (`myscript.exe` in Windows).

There is also a list of packages with known compatibility and known compatibility issues: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages, which you may find useful depending on what packages you need.

While it is not a duplicate, this question: [How to package a linked DLL and a pyd file into one self contained pyd file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637251/how-to-package-a-linked-dll-and-a-pyd-file-into-one-self-contained-pyd-file) (and another one it links) may be interesting to read.

Answer (score 3):

Of course Python requires MSVC Redistributable, any native Windows program using standard library functions requires it. Obviously, Python uses lots of them and should provide a consistent environment across all extension modules.

However, since Python 3.5 [it is bundled with an installer](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#installation-steps), so there's no need to install it manually. Python installers prior to 3.5 don't include it and I wasn't able to find any clarifications whether it's downloaded during installation or not.

By default Python also enforces [extension modules to be compiled with the same](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/windows.html) (or, since 3.5, compatible) [version of MSVC as an interpreter itself](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/windows.html). So except for some very rare cases extension modules will also use the same redistributable.

---

"Embeddable" Python releases referred by @tevemadar are NOT a "portable Python"! Here's what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution) says about their usage:

> It is intended for acting as part of another application, rather than being directly accessed by end-users.

> **Note:** The embedded distribution does not include the Microsoft C Runtime and it is the responsibility of the application installer to provide this. The runtime may have already been installed on a user’s system previously or automatically via Windows Update, and can be detected by finding `ucrtbase.dll` in the system directory.

But you still don't need them if you use PyInstaller.

---

To check whether or not redistributable files are included in your `.exe` file you could probably open it with any archiver software and see it for yourself. My guess is that they *can* be included at least if Python is installed in a single user mode, as in such case [they're installed in the Python directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65235123/11725753) as well.

Other than that, however, you should really ask your questions separately.